# How to change the line width of the lines connecting spies and the spied region

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was experimenting with the `spy` library. It worked quite well, except for influencing the line width of the spy connections when using the `connect spies` keyword, or the width of the outline of the region to be spied on. I tried to insert keywords like `ultra thick` or `line width=3mm` everywhere, but it has no effect. The manual only states *"Causes the spy-in and the spy-on nodes to be connected by a thin line."* for the `connect spies` keyword, but no options for thick lines. I also looked through every question here on tex.sx concerning the `spy` library but did not find anything.

So is it even possible to have some options passed to these lines (probably `dashed` and other things also might be useful), and if, how?

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, size=2cm, connect spies}]
    %\includegraphics[scale=1]{test.png}
    \node[above right, inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{test.png}};
    \draw[very thin, yellow] (0,0) grid (15.25,10);
    \spy[magnification=3,red,draw,line width=1mm] on (2,2) in node[ultra thick] at (3,-2);
    \spy[magnification=5,green] on (7.1,4.1) in node[line width=4mm] at (8,-2);
    \spy[magnification=10,black] on (11.8,2.8) in node[dashed,line width=1mm] at (13,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And finally, the original picture if you want to use it for experimenting:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key `spy connection path` is used to draw the connection between the `spy in` and `spy on` nodes. It is executed once both nodes have been created. By using the `connect spies` style, the `spy connection path` key is set to `\draw[thin] (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);`. This is specified in the `TikZ` manual on page 465. So in order to influence the path connecting the `spy in` and `spy on` nodes we need to specify the `spy connection path` code. This can simply be done in the `options` to the `\spy` commands.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, size=2cm}]
    \node[above right, inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{test.png}};
    \draw[very thin, yellow] (0,0) grid (15.25,10);
    \spy[magnification=3,spy connection path={\draw[thick] (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);}] on (2,2) in node at (3,-2);
    \spy[magnification=5,spy connection path={\draw[thick, green] (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);}] on (7.1,4.1) in node[green] at (8,-2);
    \spy[magnification=10,spy connection path={\draw[thick, dashed] (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);}] on (11.8,2.8) in node[dashed] at (13,-2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Spies with special connections]

**Update:** To influence the way the `on nodes` look, we need to define our own `spy scope` and use keys to change the behaviour. The following example illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    my spy on/.style={#1},
    my spy/.style={
      spy scope={
        every spy on node/.style={
          draw,
          circle, 
          size=2cm,
          my spy on,
        },
        every spy in node/.style={
          draw,
          black,
          size=2cm,
          thick,
          circle,
        },
      #1
      }
    }
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[my spy]
    \node[above right, inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{test.png}};
    \draw[very thin, yellow] (0,0) grid (15.25,10);
    \spy[magnification=3,spy connection path={\draw[thick, black] (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);}, my spy on={red, very thick}] on (2,2) in node at (3,-2);
    \spy[magnification=5,spy connection path={\draw[thick, green] (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);}] on (7.1,4.1) in node[green] at (8,-2);
    \spy[magnification=10,spy connection path={\draw[thick, dashed,black] (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);}, my spy on={green, thick}] on (11.8,2.8) in node[dashed] at (13,-2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now the `#1` in the `my spy` style allows for additional options to be added to the `spy scope`. The `my spy on` style is used to set options for the `on node`. The result looks like this:

[image: Spies with special connections and on nodes]

Comment: Very nice and very fast. I just have one nore problem: I can alter the color and style of the `spy on node` (e.g. `red, dashed`), but not the thickness. The manual states something about a `every spy on node` style on page 465, but I don't know how to use it, especially to influence every `spy` individually. Any ideas?

Comment: @TomBombadil: The problem is that the `spy using outlines` option (discussed on the same page) sets the line width to very thin. So what you would need is to specify your own `spy scope`. You can then use keys to influence how everything is drawn. I will update the answer in a second.

Comment: Yay, now I can do all kinds of weird looking spy glass things. Thanks a lot!