# show zoomed content into a frame (as in wooden frame)?

Tags: beamer

I saw an HTML presentation where zoomed elements were "framed", meaning that you could still see a part of the original slide in the background (shaded) while the zoomed content was in the foreground enclosed in a smaller frame.

To have an idea of what I mean see [framed frame in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48183/framed-frame-in-beamer)

The difference is of course that in my case I don't want to design a layout for a frame but I want an effect that applies to zoomed content and frame them into frames.

Sorry for the mess with frames!

edit: a better example of what I mean can be found in the short video here:http://www.presentation-process.com/zoom-effect-in-powerpoint.html

The zoomed content does not need to be circular but I'd like it to have some frame around it.

edit2: as noted by Tom Bombadil the spy library may be useful here. See [How to change the line width of the lines connecting spies and the spied region](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42342/how-to-change-the-line-width-of-the-lines-connecting-spies-and-the-spied-region) and [Is there a way to tune ball shading in TikZ ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/is-there-a-way-to-tune-ball-shading-in-tikz/43597#43597)

Comment: Do you mean like what the [`spy` library](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42342/how-to-change-the-line-width-of-the-lines-connecting-spies-and-the-spied-region) in [`TikZ` does](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/is-there-a-way-to-tune-ball-shading-in-tikz/43597#43597)?

Comment: @TomBombadil Yes! As long as the spied part does appear after a click like the beamer framezoom does.

Answer (score 2):

The following is taken partially from [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39231/5764) to [Including large tables in a `beamer` frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38177/5764). It showcases the extent of `\framezoom`:

From the [`beamer` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) on **11.3 Adding Anticipated zooming** (p 109):

> Anticipated zooming is necessary when you have a very complicated
>   graphic that you are not willing to simplify since, indeed, all the
>   complex details merit an explanation. In this case, use the command
>   `\framezoom`. It allows you to specify that clicking on a certain area
>   of a frame should zoom out this area. You can then explain the
>   details. Clicking on the zoomed out picture will take you back to the
>   original one.

In the above description, "graphic" might just as well have read "object", since it pertains to tables as well.

For the sake of illustration, I've highlighted a couple of entries (in red `\alert` font) within the same table I've used before, this time also shrunk down using `\resizebox` and then zoomed in on them using `\framezoom`.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
    \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
    \usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{This is a frame with a table}

      \framezoom<1><2>[border=1](0pt,11mm)(4.5em,5ex)

      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within \linewidth horizontally
      \begin{tabular}{*{27}{l}}
        \toprule
        Stuff & A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M&N&O&P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y&Z \\
        \midrule
        One   & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
        Two   & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
        Three & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
        \alert{Four}  & 26&25&24&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
        Five  & 1&\alert{2}&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
        Six   & 26&25&\alert{24}&23&22&21&20&19&18&17&16&15&14&13&12&11&10&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1 \\
        Seven & \alert{1}&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

In the above example, the border was inserted/kept for clarity. However, by default (if you remove the `border=<n>` option), it will not be displayed. `\framezoom` has the following syntax:

```
\framezoom<button overlay spec><zoomed overlay spec>[<options>](<ulx>,uly>)(<zoom width>,<zoom depth>)
```

As such, I requested a zoom of slide `<1>`, upon clicking, to be typeset on slide `<2>`, adding an optional `[border=1]` of `1pt`. The zoomed location on slide `<1>` is at coordinate `(<ulx>,<uly>)`=`(0pt,11mm)` and spans an area of `(<width>,<depth>)`=`(4.5em,5ex)`.

Comment: thank you but this is not what I meant. I inserted a link that should explain better what I want to achieve.